# matplotlib with dates

Tags: python, date, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot values as a function of the date (only hh:mm:ss, without dd/mm/yy). The code looks like this

```
dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(x_values)
plt.plot_date(dates, y_values)
```

but I get the following error

> 'numpy.string_' object has no attribute 'toordinal'.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`date2num` expects `datetime` objects.  If you have strings, use `matplotlib.dates.datestr2num`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num):

> matplotlib.dates.date2num(d): d is either a datetime instance or a sequence of datetimes.

Looks like you are giving in a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt <br>
pay_date=['2016-04-30', '2016-06-28', '2016-11-29'] 
due_date=['2016-05-02', '2016-07-31', '2016-10-29'] 
plt.plot_date(pay_date,due_date,xdate=True,ydate=True)
```

Just add the parameters `xdate=True` and `ydate=True` and it will automatically plot the dates

and finally write the following code, to print the lines

```
plt.plot(pay_date,due_date)
```